# javascript addEventListener mousedown does not fire

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, event-listener, mousedown

A simple `MouseEvent` setup is somehow not responding..

```
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener( 'pointerdown', onDown, false); // doesn't fire on safari (as expected)
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDown, false); // doesn't fire anywhere!! chrome/firefox/safari
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false); // works fine
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener( 'mouseup', oneClick, false); // works fine
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener( 'dblclick', doubleClick, false); // works fine
```

so the issue is with `mousedown` not working in any browser... I've also tried `mousedown()` with parenthesis, but still no firing. Very strange or am I missing something supersimple?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41238807/10775969

Basically chrome stopped supporting mouse events in favour of pointer events not long ago.

Wouter Coebergh covers it in good detail with plenty of references.

Comment: thanks for this, yes I'm aware of this update in Chrome, so maybe using `if (window.PointerEvent)` could help. But still, why `mousedown` not working in Safari and Firefox??

Comment: and: how come all those "old" websites using `mousedown` still work on Chrome now?