# Chrome cannot find Javascript function in html document

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have an html file and a js file. After loading the js file, trying to run any of the js methods doesn't work in chrome. They work fine in IE. In the chrome console it says that the function is not defined, but under the network tab you can see that the file is found and is loaded by the html.

I know that if I write the js inline it then works fine and using those functions work. Code below:

file stucture:

html
->index.html
js
->test.js

js: test.js

```
function myTest(){
    alert("TEST")
}
```

html: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/test.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <button onmousedown="myTest()">Move Up </button>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What error you are having?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onmousedown="myTest()">Move Up </button>
```

Unfortunetly the **onmousedown** event is no longer supported by Chrome.

You can try to use the **onclick** event which is supported by (as I think) every browser:

```
<button onclick="myTest()">Move Up </button>
```

Comment: You can read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181372/chrome-mousedown-and-mouseup-events-no-longer-working-other-browsers-are-fine

Comment: I've tried changing the code to onclick and it still doesn't work, with the same error in chrome. Same thing with onload etc. When I look at what files are loaded it does say the js file, but when open in the chrome tools its just symbols. I don't get this with my other projects and I've tried recreating the file etc and it doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. The problem was the encoding on the html document. You want to have UTF-8