# Adding an event listener to a canvas?

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, mouseevent, dom-events

I've seen similar posts to this, and watched a few tutorials, but I can't get my canvas to have an event listener. Here's what I've got:

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="599" height="575" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
ctx.addEventListener('mousedown',onDown,false);
function onDown(event){
console.log("click");
};
ctx.font = "normal 20pt Pixelate";
ctx.fillStyle= "gray";
ctx.fillRect  (0,0, 700, 700);
</script>
```

So how do I add this? I have a link to an external js script after this that needs a reference to a click to change a variable, but even putting the event listener on there, which is located after the declaration of the canvas, still can't establish it. The browser says ctx.addEventListener is not a function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181372/chrome-mousedown-and-mouseup-events-no-longer-working-other-browsers-are-fine/41238807#41238807

Answer (score 1):

The event listener should be applied to the `HTMLCanvasElement` (the actual DOM element) rather than to the `RenderingContext`.

For example, this would get your sample to work:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("ctx");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',onDown,false);
```

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget